# How is more correctly to work in Angular with modules?

Tags: angular, module

Is it better to have one module for each component in Angular, or to work without custom modules (I mean component module); I'm a beginner.

And before, I worked without a module for each component (I mean, I was creating a component and passing it to declarations in `app.module.ts`), but this week I found out a tutorial, where the guy was creating a module for each component.

Any tips or suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I vsn tell you what I do, I follow this protocol for modules and my apps,

1. Each feature - individual modules
   (let us say you have a landing page, customer details page, about us page so each of these page is made up of multiple components and each page will have its own functionality, I design one module for each of these feature modules.)
2. External library dependency - one module
   (Lets us assume you are using material library, to manage its dependencies in main app I would use one module, you can find its reference in material library documentation also.)
3. Shared features - one module,
   ( If you have some shared logic such as pipes, common logic, app wide common service I design a shared module for such features)
4. Think as a group - individual module for each,
   ( Whatever you do in angular and if you can group them together as a group which is logical try to think for a module.)

**Note: Don't create unnecessary modules for each task, only make them such that it gets easier for you to manage**

Do read this document for more details,
[Angular style guide](http://%20https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the best approach is to create a module for each component.

That

- Simplify your module imports in unit test
- Lazy loading for the win
- Separate the concerns
- Much easier refactor
- ...